# ArrayList implementation C++

Tags: c++, arraylist

I need to write an IntArray implementation for college. I'm wondering if my code could be better. Is it efficient. In the header file are the methods listed that we need to write. thanks

Header file :

```
 #ifndef INTARRAY_H_
 #define INTARRAY_H_

 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class IntArray{
 private:
     int length;
     int * data;
public:
    IntArray(int size = 0);
    IntArray(const IntArray& other);
    IntArray& operator=(const IntArray& original);

    int getSize() const { return length; };
    int& operator[](unsigned int i);
    void resize(unsigned int size);
    void insertBefore(int value, int index);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const IntArray& list);

    ~IntArray(){ delete[] data; };

 };
 #endif
```

Cpp file:

```
 #include "IntArray.h"

 IntArray::IntArray(int size){
     length = size;
     data = new int[size];
     for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
         data[i] = 0;
     }
 }

 IntArray::IntArray(const IntArray& other){
     length = other.length;
     data = new int[length];
     for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
         data[i] = other.data[i];
     }
 }

IntArray& IntArray::operator =(const IntArray& other){
if(this = &other){
    return *this;
}
length = other.length;
data = new int[length];
for(int i = 0; i <length;i++){
    data[i] = other[i];
}
return *this;
}

 int& IntArray::operator[](unsigned int i){
      if(i>=this->length) throw "Index out of bounds";
      return data[i];
 }

 ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const IntArray& list){
      for(int i=0; i<list.getSize(); i++){
         out << list.data[i] << " ";
      }
     return out;
 }

 void IntArray::resize(unsigned size){
     if (size <= length){
        length = size;
        return;
     }
     int * temparr = new int[size];
     // copy data
     for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        temparr[i] = data[i];
     }
     delete [] data; 
     data = temparr; 
     length = size; 
 }

 void IntArray::insertBefore(int value, int index){
     resize(length+1);
     for(int i=length-1; i>index; i--){
          data[i] = data[i-1];
     }
     data[index] = value;
  }
```

Comment: If this working code then the question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: You can ask for reviews at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could enable your compiler warnings (preferably all of them) and then make your code compile without them.

Comment: Also you might want to read about the Single Responsibility Principle and the Rule of Zero. Your code is following neither of them.

Comment: i would use explicit constructors, and #pragma once

Comment: Your assignment operator is broken. Think of what happens if the LHS of the assignment has length smaller than the RHS.

Comment: No, you don't make a `new int[length]`, that is the point. Think of it, come on.

Comment: You don't do that anywhere in your assignment operator.

Comment: The. Assignment. Operator. Where else?

Answer (score 0):

The adding of next methods will make your container more convinient to use:

```
void pushFront(int value);
int popFront();
void pushBack(int value);
int popBack();
void clearAll();
```

Also, using of iterators make containers more efficient. You can read about them here: [Iterator design pattern in C++](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator/cpp/1)

Comment: Denis, welcome to SO :) Please, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge :) And please, if you link anything out of StackOverflow, you should add some (short) description and explanation (that link can go 404 and this piece of information will be gone... It is also [rule](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) here on SO.

Comment: It's probably better to focus on the posted functionality before adding to the question. Either way, it's off topic for this site.